# MIDI file generated by using MusicSequenceFileCreate has Sysex MIDI message (iOS 16.0.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, midi, audiotoolbox

I am using the `MusicSequenceFileCreate` method to generate a MIDI file from a beat-based `MusicSequence`. In iOS 16.0.2 devices, the file that is created has a Sysex MIDI message added (not by me) to the file at time 0:

f0 2a 11 67 40 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f7

Sysex messages are manufacturer dependent, a file with this Sysex message can't be read into apps like Nanostudio, Ableton, Zenbeats, which is a problem. It can only be read by GarageBand. Is there a way for `MusicSequenceFileCreate` to not add this Sysex MIDI message and basically work like it worked before iOS 16?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I've edited the original post to make it clearer.

Comment: Apple has confirmed they believe this is a bug on their side. Will update when there is a fix.

Comment: Other editors should be able to read the file and ignore the unknown SysEx event. However, the length in the event (0x2A = 42 bytes) is incorrect (it's only 41 bytes of data) which messes up the reading of the rest of the file.

However, the bug does seem to be gone as of iOS 16.2, if not earlier.

Comment: This bug was fixed in iOS 16.1.